# How a python-macro executed by the libreoffice python can call a python-script executed by a python-version of a virtual environment?

Tags: python, libreoffice

Could you please show me a way, how a libreOffice python-macro calls a python-script.py to be executed by the python-version of a virtual environment, with a new console window for output, on platform windows 10?

That would be nice, thanks in advance.

In the libreoffice - python-macro

```
def makro(): 
    import subprocess
 
    subprocess.call(["virtualEnvironmentPath/Scripts/python.exe" , "python-script.py" , "testarg"], shell=True)
```

In python-script.py:

```
import sys
print(sys.executable)
input() #to prevent immediately closing the output window
```

But the content of python-script.py was seemingly not executed, at least no console/console output could be found.

Edit:

typo, there was a missing whitespace in the question.

list syntax, for subprocess() list syntax adapted

input(), added input() in case the window was closed automatically, but this changes nothing, still no output and thus seemingly python-script.py is not executed.

Comment: Note you can [format your code](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks), both for readability and (for python) executability.

Comment: You don't have a space between your script name and the argument.  Just make it a list and let `subprocess` build it:  `["virtual.../python.exe","python-script.py","testarg"]`.

Comment: Thanks @TimRoberts for your reply. I adapted the list syntax, which is pretty convenient. But even if the program runs without an error, still I don't have an output, so somehow the python-script.py is not executed.

Comment: Where are you expecting to see output?  `subprocess.call` doesn't save the stdout, and your function doesn't return anything.

Comment: Thank you @TimRoberts, I want to see an output to the console and I don't know how to do that. I was trying to archive that within a subprocess executed by a different python, since in the python-makro seemingly print() is not allowed, at least it does not work for me. So I was hoping that inside a subprocess print() will work. So thanks to your answer I can assume, that python-script.py is executed. But can you help me how to print ()?

Comment: Well, if you check the subprocess documentation, you'll see that `check_output` runs the command, waits for it to finish, and returns its output as a string.  Note that you have no idea what "stdout" is in the context of a LIbreOffice macro.  There's no promise that it's going to print anywhere visible.

Comment: Mhm, okay I understand, so there is no way to use a console for output when a libreOffice python-makro is used?

Comment: This question involves virtual environments, subprocess calls, and LibreOffice macros all in one, which makes it hard to answer. If you're asking about LibreOffice python macros, yes, there are ways to output to a console, such as the one provided by [APSO](https://extensions.libreoffice.org/en/extensions/show/apso-alternative-script-organizer-for-python).